# Return xml/json based on content type

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am using spring rest to create handle rest api creation in the project . The rest method is annotated with the following.

```
@GetMapping(value = FETCH_ALL,produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

I have added the following dependancy to the maven project

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am using postman to make test the api and i am passing *Content-Type* in the header as *application/json* but it still returns me the xml format.

I am not able to figure out what i have missed in the configuration to return the content the user is requesting for

TIA

Comment: You have to specify Accept header. Try to add Accept header in postman

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Do accept it, if it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify Accept Header in your request.

```
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Thanks , In fiddler `Content-Type:application/xml` works but in postman it doesn't instead it gives `Json` response from asp.net wep api. But using `Accept Header` for `xml` response works in both fiddler and postman.